# Comparing different tables from different databases

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using c#, asp.net 
I have two different tables from two different databases. 
Both Have one field in common that I am interested in say custid 
I have assigned both to data tables but what I would like to do is this 
Compare the two datatables (maybe with a dataview, which I have never used before)
 to see what custid are missing from either table, 
then i can insert or delete them from the first table , as I want the first table to have the same custid's as the second table.

```
  Table 1          Table 2
  1                1 
  2                          - want to delete from table 1
  3                3
                   4         - want to add to table 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why see in datagridview, you can even automate it. loop on Table1 check each custid and delete if not found in Table2, similarly loop on Table2 and add to Table1 if not found. If you are still interesting in viewing them in datagridview, you can refer `http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DB-Invader-A-Database-6fd576f8` . It is for win app.

Comment: No not a datagridview, a  dataview so I dont have to do loops.

Comment: Will you be (a)showing both the tables to user, or (b)simply performing add delete as per condition given above. If (b) is the case then you can make a join on two datatables on custid and filterout rows to be deleted and added. If (a) then you need to also show add/delete button as required on said row, even then you can join two datatables (Full Outer) and display button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't want to display the data just manipulate it

What I did in the end was

```
        string [] servercustomers = new string [servercustomertable.lenght];
        for (i = 0; i < servercustomertable.length; i++)
          {
             // run query to see if current record exists in localtable
             // if it does update it
             // if it doesnt create it
             servercustomer[i] = servercustomertable.Rows[i]["Custid"];
          }
        // check through the localtable
        for (i = 0; i < localcustomertable.length; i++)
          {   bool recordexist = false;
              // check through the array to see if the custid is there
              for (j = 0; j < servercustomer.length; j++)
                 {
                     if (servercustomer[j] = localcustomertable.Rows[i]["custId"])
                        {
                            recordexists = true;
                            break;
                        }
                      if(!recordexists)
                           // delete the record from the local table
                   }
          }
```

Thanks for all your help
Rachael